# Override default (data center) alarm

Tags: vmware-vcenter

If we set an alarm at the datacenter level, is there a way to override it for a particular VM? For example lets say we want our general alarm definition to trigger yellow for a VM at 80% CPU. But there's one particular VM that is alwas at 90% CPU, and we don't want to see an alarm for that one VM.

Is there a way to exclude or override the datacenter level alarm defintion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general in VC children inherit parent permissions/objects etc. so logic says no you can't.

That said you could try manually creating a trigger set to 91% or whatever and assign that to this particular VM. It might override the parent trigger, worth a try.

Otherwise call VMWare's support desk - you'll have a contract as v4 is less than 12 months old.